# C# MongoDB Atlas results in a DnsClient Error: The response seems to be truncated without TC flag set

Tags: c#, mongodb, dns, atlas

I use this to initialize my MongoDB client:

```cs
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString("mongodb+srv://REDACTED");
MongoClient client = new(settings);
```

I'm receiving the following debug message when running my C# application that uses a MongoDB Atlas database:

```cs
DnsClient Error: 91 : [DnsClient.LookupClient] Query 14661 via UDP => test.wbln178.mongodb.net IN TXT error parsing the response. The response seems to be truncated without TC flag set! Re-trying via TCP anyways.
DnsClient.DnsResponseParseException: Response parser error, 512 bytes available, tried to read 4 bytes at index 509.
Cannot read more Int32.
[REDACTED].
   at DnsClient.DnsDatagramReader.ReadUInt32NetworkOrder()
   at DnsClient.DnsRecordFactory.ReadRecordInfo()
   at DnsClient.DnsMessageHandler.GetResponseMessage(ArraySegment`1 responseData)
   at DnsClient.DnsUdpMessageHandler.Query(IPEndPoint server, DnsRequestMessage request, TimeSpan timeout)
   at DnsClient.LookupClient.ResolveQuery(IReadOnlyList`1 servers, DnsQuerySettings settings, DnsMessageHandler handler, DnsRequestMessage request, LookupClientAudit audit)
```

This started appearing out of nowhere without me changing any of the connection code. It eventually succeeds, but currently this delays the startup of the application by about 10 seconds.

Comment: At this stage, seems to be more a problem of the DNS server replying to you. `dig TXT test.wbln178.mongodb.net +notcp` works fine and does not need truncation signal (response size of 343 bytes, well under 512, so not matching the log line you quote). So maybe the code (library) is wrong, but you are not even specifying which versions you use...

Comment: Where is the request?  The client has to connect to the server, then send the request, and finally get the response.  The connection is part of the request.  It looks like the request is not completing and then a retry is occurring and passing.  Without see entire code I cannot determine why the first request is failing.

Comment: I use the newest version, 2.17.0. Either way, the issue disappeared on its own after some time.